# Displaying text to labels

Tags: java, swing, label

I am new to programming  and am looking for advice on how to display my questions i have made in the below code to my lblScenario(label i made).The technique i used does not work any help would be much appreciated :}

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class MoralGameGUI 
{
    private JLabel lblScenario;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;
    int score;



    public MoralGameGUI()
    {
        frame=new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Moral Game");
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton btnYes = new JButton("Yes");
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnYes, BorderLayout.WEST);


        JButton btnNo = new JButton("No");
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNo, BorderLayout.EAST);

        JButton btnGetScenario = new JButton("Get Scenario ");
        btnGetScenario.addActionListener(new ScenarioHandler());
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnGetScenario, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JLabel lblScenario = new JLabel("Scenario");
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblScenario, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        JLabel lblAnswer = new JLabel("answer");
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblAnswer, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panel= new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }


    class ScenarioHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {

    int index = (int)(Math.random()*20);

            if (index == 2){
                lblScenario.setText("nd save her?");
            }
            else if (index ==3){    
                lblScenario.setText("A magic evil gene asks you if you would give up all your fingers and toes to help raise funds for a ugandan princess");
            }

            else if (index ==4){
                lblScenario.setText("A woman with a rubbish dress on ask you for yours do you give it to her ");
            }
            else if (index ==5){
                lblScenario.setText("A man with no shoes asks for your hand in marriage what do you say");
            }
            else if (index ==6){
                lblScenario.setText("your stuck in a derilict prison and you find a loaf of bread in the darkness do you eat it ");
            }
            else if (index ==7){
                lblScenario.setText("The jam has a thick layer of mould over it do you eat it?");
            }
            else if (index ==8){
                lblScenario.setText("15 giant racoons try to stral your humous what do you shout out them");
            }
            else if (index ==9){
                lblScenario.setText("your wedding dress has been lost do you buy some sweet reeboks instead");
            }
            else if (index ==10){
                lblScenario.setText("ten lizards attack do you fight back");
            }
            else if (index ==11){
                lblScenario.setText("there is no bread left in the kitchen do you cry?");
            }
            else if (index ==12){
                lblScenario.setText("do you sell your soul for a delicious pack of oreos");
            }
            else if (index ==13){
                lblScenario.setText("Have you got a mans voice");
            }
            else if (index ==14){   
                lblScenario.setText("have you got the heart of a lion");
            }

            else if (index ==15){   
                lblScenario.setText("no eyebrowns dosent hold you back do you agree?");
            }

            else if (index ==16){
                lblScenario.setText("spiders come do you stand your ground");
            }
            else if (index ==17){
                lblScenario.setText(" or no?");
            }
            else if (index ==18){
                lblScenario.setText("are you old?");
            }
            else if (index ==19){   
                lblScenario.setText("......?");
            }
            else if (index ==20){
                lblScenario.setText(".........?");
            }





        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new MoralGameGUI();
    }
}

class YesNoHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {



    }
}
```

ignore the spellinng mistakes and thanks again :)

Comment: The question itself is not very clear. What are your doubts about?

Comment: The first thing I would highlight is ScenarioHandler.actionPerformed method. What you're trying to to there is better achieved using array or dictionary to map indices to labels.

Answer (score 1):

In `MoralGameGUI()`, you are re-declaring a new `JLabel` object with the same name as the instance variable (which stays `null`, and causes crashes when you call methods on it, like `setText`) :

```
JLabel lblScenario = new JLabel("Scenario");
```

Just do this, to assign the value to the real one :

```
lblScenario = new JLabel("Scenario");
```

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor, you do:

```
JLabel lblScenario = new JLabel("Scenario");
```

As such, you are **creating a new JLabel**, instead of **initializing the original one**. So, this new JLabel is added to your frame. But, in the `actionPerformed` method, this new JLabel is not visible. It has access to the JLabel which you declared previously. But, that method is not in your JFrame, and hence any changes to it, are not possible.

Hence you fail in your attempt.

You must do:

```
lblScenario = new JLabel("Scenario");
```